# Extracting matching lines from a CSV

Tags: csv, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa, ip, 1.2.3.4, 
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa, ip, 4.5.6.7, 
bacd8a9d-807f-4ae9-95d2-f7cc17222cab, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, silly string
bacd8a9d-807f-4ae9-95d2-f7cc17222cab, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, crazy town
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c, ip, 8.9.0.1, wild wood
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, wacky tabacky
611f8cf5-f6f2-4f3a-ad24-12245652a7bd, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, cuckoo cachoo
```

I would like to extract a list of just the unique GUIDs where

1. The GUID doesn't have a 0.0.0.0/0 in column 3
2. column 3 matches 0.0.0.0/0 and there is more than one instance of the GUID and where at least one of the matches is not 0.0.0.0/0

In this case, the desired output would be:

```
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c
```

Trying to think through this, I feel like I should make an array/list of the unique GUIDs, and then kinda grep the matching lines and run the process of the two conditions above, but I just don't know the best way to go about this in a short script or perhaps grep/awk/sort/cut one liner.  Appreciate any help!

(the original file is a 4 column csv where the 4th column is often null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F',[[:space:]]*' '$3 !~ /^(0\.){3}0\/0/{ guids[$1] }
                       END{ for(k in guids) print k }' testfile.txt
```

The output:

```
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$3 !~/0\.0\.0\.0\/0/ && !seen[$1]++{print $1}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `$3 !~/0\.0\.0\.0\/0/` field3 doesn't match regexp and (`&&`)
- `!seen[$1]++` field1 not seen before ( whenever awk sees duplicate key (`$1`), array value will be incremented by 1, we used logical negation to print value only once )

  - `!` is logical negation operator
  - `seen` is array
  - `$1` is array key
  - `++` increment operator (current context post increment)
- `print $1` print field1

**Test Results:**

```
$ cat infile
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa, ip, 1.2.3.4, 
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa, ip, 4.5.6.7, 
bacd8a9d-807f-4ae9-95d2-f7cc17222cab, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, silly string
bacd8a9d-807f-4ae9-95d2-f7cc17222cab, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, crazy town
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c, ip, 8.9.0.1, wild wood
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, wacky tabacky
611f8cf5-f6f2-4f3a-ad24-12245652a7bd, ip, 0.0.0.0/0, cuckoo cachoo

$ awk -F, '$3 !~/0\.0\.0\.0\/0/ && !seen[$1]++{print $1}' infile
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could be done with a three-step pipeline:

1. Filter out rows where column 3 is `0.0.0.0/0`: `grep -v '^[^,]*,[^,]*, *0\.0\.0\.0/0,'`
2. Select column 1: `cut -d, -f1`
3. Only print unique elements: `sort -u` (alternatively, if all duplicates are adjacent, `uniq`)

```
grep -v '^[^,]*,[^,]*, *0\.0\.0\.0/0,' | cut -d, -f1 | sort -u
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not working for me.

`cat testfile.txt | grep -v '^[^,]*,[^,]*, *0\.0\.0/0,' | cut -d, -f1 | sort -u
611f8cf5-f6f2-4f3a-ad24-12245652a7bd
64fe12c7-b50c-4f63-b292-99f4ed74e5aa
bacd8a9d-807f-4ae9-95d2-f7cc17222cab
db86d211-0b09-4a8f-b222-a21a54ad2f9c`

The command produces the 4 uniques in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another possible solution, similar (but uglier and using more than one command) than the other proposed `awk` solution. If I understood the question correctly, your condition #2 is already taken into account by #1. In any case, the following `awk+sort` worked for me:

```
awk -F, '$3!~/^ 0\.0\.0\.0\/0/ {print $1}' file.csv | sort -u
```

Using the `-u` (unique) flag on `sort`, you'll exclude duplicates. Not completely foolproof, but works in this case.

Hope it helps!